# Are there options for cropping inline-block line breaks in CSS?

Tags: css

I have an interesting issue I've never encountered in css before. A client is asking if the first blue box in the image below can crop after the word "Association" instead of spanning the full width of the parent.

That's an inline-block element with width set to auto.

```
display: inline-block;
width: auto;
padding: .5em;
```

Nothing special, right? As you can see by box 2, The director of marketing has his title cropped correctly. So why is it that css chooses to display the blue background nearly the full width of the parent when the text requires more than one line?

Does anyone know of some css property that can be applied to make an inline-block element crop at the end of words? Forgive if I am failing to articulate this. I'm not really sure how to structure this question.

[image]

If it helps to know, I cannot make a special case for this item. It is a CMS based system and the job titles can be anything. Making a special case, like `max-width:90%` wouldn't work, especially considering mobile break points and such. We would have to write cases for anything with a long title, and specific to that title's unique set of words, so that's pretty much out of the question.

Here's a fiddle to mess with if you want to see it in action. They styles are pretty much the same, at least the important parts.
https://jsfiddle.net/4f7jj7L8/

Comment: I may be misunderstndning but perhaps the use of nth-child ( https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/) to target this div specifically? Then simply adjusting the padding on the left and right for the line breaks you desire?

Comment: Maybe with a float? Ok,  it's a bit tricky and you'll need to clear after, but that could do the job.

Comment: You can add a `fixed width`, or add a `<br>` when you want to "break" the sentence.

Comment: @romuleald - Float has the same results. Line broken titles still have the background span the full width. mk14 - I could give it a unique ID if that was viable. But I don't intend to keep updating the client's css every time they add a new entry with a ridiculous title. and vucko - fixed width would also be high maintenance since it will be unknown what titles they add and where the line breaks will happen.

Comment: If you add the float on the element with the background? It must follow the content width this way.

Comment: @romuleald - true, it must. But yet, it crops the same as you see above. You can check my fiddle and change that h5 to `display:block; float:left;` to see it is the same. Very curious side effect in css.

Comment: Mh ok, you maybe need a display: table-caption; and in the CMS inserting non breakable space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***If*** the CMS entry itself can have the line break (not a `br` tag but a normal linebreak), then there's a simple solution:

CSS:

```
.job > h5 {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

HTML (Generated):

```
     <h5>Director 
of Association Management Services</h5>
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/4f7jj7L8/4/

Comment: Yeah it's just wordpress so that could work. The issue with white-space:pre is that scaling down results in some overflow issues that don't happen otherwise. And because I don't know the words in advance, I don't think I can set specific break points to accommodate for this. Plus, WP can handle the `<br>` but not conditionally unless I expect the client to add classes to those br tags... so I might see a title like `Associate Director<br class="br1">of Marketing and<br class="br2">Sales` and choose which to display:none with media queries. That's a lot for a simple issue.

Comment: It's still simple, I updated the answer for you. Now it uses `pre-line` instead of `pre` and accomplishes what you need. Meaning you still get the line-break when it is in the html and on narrower screens the line breaks automatically to fit the width.

Comment: Yup. pre-line is it. That's probably going to be as close as they can get. I'm accepting this as a perfectly viable solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not automatically.

The [width of an inline-block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inlineblock-width) is defined as

> If 'width' is 'auto', the used value is the [shrink-to-fit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) width as for
>   floating elements.
>
> Calculation of the shrink-to-fit width is similar to calculating the
>   width of a table cell using the automatic table layout algorithm.
>   Roughly: calculate the preferred width by formatting the content
>   without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur,
>   and also calculate the preferred *minimum* width, e.g., by trying all
>   possible line breaks. CSS 2.1 does not define the exact algorithm.
>   Thirdly, find the *available width*: in this case, this is the width of
>   the containing block minus the used values of 'margin-left',
>   'border-left-width', 'padding-left', 'padding-right',
>   'border-right-width', 'margin-right', and the widths of any relevant
>   scroll bars.
>
> Then the shrink-to-fit width is: min(max(preferred minimum width,
>   available width), preferred width).

If the text is long enough, the preferred width will be greater than the available width. So the inline-block will fill all the available width.

However, you can avoid that inserting explicit line breaks (e.g. `<br />`) at the desired places.

```css
.job {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
h5 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: #ff0000;
}
p {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="job">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <h2>Some Name</h2>
  <h5>Director<br />of<br />Association<br />Management<br />Services</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor set amit</p>
</div>
<div class="job">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <h2>Some Name</h2>
  <h5>Director of Sales</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor set amit</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible — the *highlight* effect can be cleverly emulated using a mix of:

1. Declaring the element as `inline`, so it collapses to content width
2. Using a combination of box shadows to cover all four edges
3. Using relative positioning and a left offset to compensate for extra space taken up by the box shadow

Here's the minimal CSS that works:

```
h5{
    display:inline;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height: 1.75em;
    position: relative;
    left: .5em;
    background:#ff0000;
    box-shadow: 0 -.25em 0 .5em #ff0000,
                0 .25em 0 .5em #ff0000,
                .25em 0 0 .25em #ff0000,
                -.25em 0 0 .25em #ff0000;
}
```

And it looks like this on Chrome v41, OS X 10.10.3:

[image: Result]

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/4f7jj7L8/2/

Comment: The problem is that the element is no longer a box: http://i.stack.imgur.com/f41mt.png

Comment: Awww I had high hopes for this one. But as Oriol just said, it is no longer a box... but I wonder if I can trick that somehow with js or something. I am shameless. I will employ js on something like this if I have to.

Comment: @Oriol Strange — I'm not seeing what you are seeing http://i.imgur.com/F8sIgr2.png

Comment: I think we mean the red background does not encompass all words as a single box instead of each line having a box fitting the needs of that line alone.

Comment: Strange. It seems like it works on Safari and Chrome here, but breaks down in Firefox :/

Comment: It seems Firefox only allows box-shadow to overflow the first and last line boxes, but not the other ones. This is the standard behavior. The desired one can be achieved adding [`box-decoration-break: clone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break).